# Explanation on converting Join Query to a Nested Subquery

Tags: mysql, join

I know this question comes up a lot. But, I can't put my finger on why this is so. I'm doing Q1 from the Introduction to Databases course at Stanford: https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/DB/SQL/SelfPaced/courseware/ch-sql/seq-exercise-sql_social_query_core/

> Find the names of all students who are friends with someone named Gabriel.

The query would be:

```
SELECT h1.name
FROM Highschooler h1
INNER JOIN Friend f1 ON (h1.ID = f1.ID1)
INNER JOIN Highschooler h2 ON (h2.ID = f1.ID2)
WHERE h2.name = 'Gabriel'
```

Looking at answers online, this is equivalent to:

```
SELECT name
FROM Highschooler
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID1
             FROM Friend
             WHERE ID2 IN (SELECT ID FROM Highschooler WHERE name='Gabirel') )
```

Why is this so? Is there an intuitive way to explain why these two queries are equal?

Comment: Good question. Do you understand the syntax between both of them? I mean, do you understand well exactly how a join works? Can you see in your head visually what's going on w/ the join? I think if you did you would be closer to understanding how they're similar.

Answer (score 0):

For the nested query:

1. From the `Highschoolers` table, find Gabriel's ID.
2. From the `Friends` table, find the IDs of everyone who's friends with the result of 1.
3. From the `Highschoolers` table, find the names of everyone in the result of 2.

For the join query:

1. For everyone in `Highschoolers`, find the IDs of all their friends by matching `Highschoolers.ID` to `Friends.ID1`.
2. Find the names of all friends by matching `Friends.ID2` to a second instance of `Highschoolers.ID`.

Because we need to look at two rows from `Highschoolers` at the same time, we need two separate references to the table. You could imagine this as having two identical copies of `Highschoolers`, as long as you remember that there's *really* only one copy, you're just using it twice.

3. Take only those records where the friend's name is "Gabriel."

Essentially, the two queries approach the same problem from opposite ends.

Hope that helps.